# How to filter only by a single column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql which gives the following result.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4mPh.jpg)

I want to filter the results by the first column "eventid", where only the first three results of the particular month will be shown.

For example, in the image there are four eventids for month 12, in the new result there will be only three.

The following is the sql.

```
select eventid, qtysold, pricepaid, qtysold*pricepaid as total_sales_by_tickets,
"date_part"('month'::text, saletime) AS month_id 
from public.sales
group by eventid, qtysold, pricepaid, total_sales_by_tickets, month_id
ORDER BY qtysold desc, "date_part"('month'::text, saletime desc;
```

Comment: What's the point of `GROUP BY` without aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select eventid, qtysold, pricepaid, qtysold*pricepaid as 
       total_sales_by_tickets,
       date_trunc('month'::text, saletime) AS month_id 
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by eventid, date_trunc('month'::text, saletime) order by saletime) as seqnum
      from public.sales s
     ) s
where seqnum <= 3
order by qtysold desc, date_trunc('month'::text, saletime) desc;
```

I am not sure why you are using `"date_part"()`.  I prefer `date_trunc()` for selecting the month part of a date.

In addition, I don't think the aggregation is necessary.  You certainly are not using any aggregation functions, so `group by` seems superfluous.

Comment: Thank you. I found row_number and was wondering if it could be the solution. The reason for date_part is that it gives a better result...a numeric '12' instead of '2008-11-01 00:00:00.000000'. Also the result does not filter properly, I see four rows with value and so on. But this is a good start.

Comment: @AverageJoe . . . It might give "12", but nothing in your query is restricting the data to a single year, so it will include data for all Decembers.